# How to disable Code sniffer checking if namespaces are present

Tags: php, phpcodesniffer

I have downloaded Code sniffer from this [page](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_CodeSniffer/download/2.7.1) (manual installation) and i have import it in my PHP storm IDE (i have included phpcs localy). Since i'm using cakephp i and namespaces are not needed i wan't to disable code sniffer for checking if class has namespaces. How do i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to disable `ClassDeclarationSniff` [rule](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/blob/master/src/Standards/PSR1/Sniffs/Classes/ClassDeclarationSniff.php). Please be aware that the side-effect will be disabling `One class per file` check.

Tutorial how to create your own custom coding standard you can find on https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/using-php-code-sniffer-tool.html in `Configuring a local Code Sniffer script` section.